# For all finite sets $A$ and $B$, $\{ f:B\to A \}$ is finite and its (finite) cardinality is $|A|^{|B|}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In Halmos' Naive Set Theory (towards the end of the "Arithmetic" chapter) he mentions the titular claim:

For all finite sets $A$ and $B$, $\{ f:B\to A \}$ is finite and its (finite) cardinal is $|A|^{|B|}$ where $|A|$ and $|B|$ are the (finite) cardinals of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Halmos does not provide a hint for this proof. Can the Math StackExchange community provide a hint?

*Let it be known that I intuitively accept the claim, but the proof I find difficult. The proof boils down to constructing a bijection between $\{f:B\to A\}$ and $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:n<|A|^{|B|}\}$. I have a feeling it will require a proof by induction.

Comment: Shouldn't this be $|B|^{|A|}$?!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/how-to-understand-the-definition-of-cardinal-exponentiation

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the notation $B^A$ to denote the collection of all maps $A\to B$ (I hope this is plebeian enough for Cameron!).

We will show that $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$ by inducting on $|A|$.

The base case $|A|=0$ holds since there is a unique map $\varnothing\to B$. If this seems iffy to you, then you could make the base case $|A|=1$ and convince yourself that there are exactly $|B|$ maps $A\to B$ when $|A|=1$. Either way, the base case holds.

Now, suppose inductively that the claim is true whenever $|A|\leq n$ and assume $|A|=n+1$. Then there exists a $*\in A$ and 
\begin{align*}
|B^A|
&\overset{\circ}{=} |B^{A\setminus\{*\}}|\times|B^{\{*\}}| \\
&= |B|^{|A\setminus\{*\}|}\times|B|^{|\{*\}|} \\
&= |B|^{n}\times|B| \\
&= |B|^{n+1} \\
&= |B|^{|A|}
\end{align*}
The only equality that is not immediately obvious is the one marked with a $\circ$. Can you prove this equality?

Comment: Oh goodness. I think you should tone down the jargon a bit. This is a bit scary of a post for someone of OP's level.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Just having a bit of fun. I hope OP survived the storm!

Comment: The $\circ$ equality is not obvious for me (to prove), but the hint with the proof approach (proof by induction) is very helpful!

Comment: Hint to prove the circle: every function $A\to B$ defines functions $A\setminus\{*\}\to B$ and $\{*\}\to B$. Conversely, given $A\setminus\{*\}\to B$ and $\{*\}\to B$ we can define a function $A\to B$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I can't believe it! OP lives!

Answer (score 1):

The cardinality of the set of functions $A \to B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$, not $|A|^{|B|}$.

The proof of this fact by induction on $|A|$ is reasonably straightforward. This is probably enough of a hint; let me know in the comments if you want more help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proof is much simpler than what has been indicated. These are finite sets. How many ways can you form a function $f:A\rightarrow B$? There are $|A|$ elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{|A|}$ of $A$. For the first element, there are $|B|$ possible values to choose for $f(a_1)$. For each of these, there are $|B|$ possible values to choose for $f(a_2)$. Continuing for each of the $|A|$ elements of $A$, we see that there are altogether
$$\underbrace{|B|\cdot|B|\cdot\ldots\cdot|B|}_{|A|\textrm{ factors}}=|B|^{|A |}$$
distinct functions since each distinct choice of assignments determines a distinct function.